# Write down the backward equations for $P_{12}$ and $P_{21}$ and use the symmetry of Q to solve these equations.

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

***Hint: Whenever confronted with an ordinary differential equation of the form x′(t) = ax(t)+b(t), it might be beneficial to consider the function y(t) = $e^{−at}x(t)$.***

$$Q =  \left[ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 2\lambda & 0 \\
    \lambda & 0 & \lambda \\
    0 & 2\lambda & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]
$$

So the backward Kolmogorov's equation I got is:
$$P'_{12}(t) = 2\lambda P_{22}(t) -2\lambda P_{12}(t) $$
$$P'_{21}(t) = \lambda P_{11}(t) + \lambda P_{31}(t) - 2\lambda P_{21}(t) $$

I am lost about using the symmetry of Q to solve these equations.

Edit: I was asked to provide more information regarding what are $P_{ij}$ and how it is related to Q.

So $P_{ij}(t)$ = $P(X(t) =j| X(0) = i)$ be the probability that the continuous time Markov chain X(t), having started in sate i, will be in state j at time t.

The differential equation I got (as above) is by using Kolmogorov's Backward Equations $P'_{ij}(t)$ = $\sum_{k\neq i}^m q_{ik}p_{kj}(t) - v_{i}p_{ij}(t)$. Where $v_{i}$ is the transition rate out of state i and $q_{ij}$ is the transition rate from i to j ($v_{i}$$p_{ij}$).

I believe after solving the differential equation the answer is suppose to be like $p_{12}$ = $e^{t(-2 \lambda)}$. But I am not sure how to get this.

Comment: It would help if you provide some context. What are$P_{ij}$s and how are they related to $Q$?

Comment: @stochastic I have updated my question with more information. I hope it helps. I'm still struggling with it.

Comment: Are $v_i$s all equal to $2\lambda$?

Comment: @stochastic yes, all  are equal to $2 \lambda$. So $v_1$ = $v_2$ = $v_3$ = $2 \lambda$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution doesn't really use the symmetries of $Q$, but it may be useful to have the answer.

We are solving the set of equations given by
$$
P'(t) = QP(t) - 2\lambda P(t) = (Q-2\lambda I)P(t)\equiv AP(t)
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix, and I have defined $A\equiv Q-2\lambda I$. This is a linear differential equation with the formal solution
$$P(t) = e^{At}P(0)= e^{At}I = e^{At}$$
where I have used the fact that the transition matrix at time zero is the identitiy matrix $I$.

So how do we exponentiate the matrix $At$? We can do this by decomposing $A$ as 
$$A = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -2 \lambda  & 2 \lambda  & 0 \\
 \lambda  & -2 \lambda  & \lambda  \\
 0 & 2 \lambda  & -2 \lambda  \\
\end{array}
\right) = VDV^{-1} = \frac14\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -4 \lambda  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 \lambda  & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -2 & 1 \\
 -2 & 0 & 2 \\
 1 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
where $V$ is matrix whose columns are eigenvectors of $A$ and the $D$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $At$ as the diagonal entries. Now exponential of $A$ is given by 
$$P(t) = e^{At} = Ve^{Dt}V^{-1} = \frac14\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 e^{-4 \lambda t}  & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & e^{-2 \lambda t}  & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & -2 & 1 \\
 -2 & 0 & 2 \\
 1 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) = \frac14\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 e^{-4 \lambda  t}+2 e^{-2 \lambda  t}+1 & 2-2 e^{-4 \lambda  t} & e^{-4 \lambda  t}-2 e^{-2 \lambda  t}+1 \\
 1-e^{-4 \lambda  t} & 2 e^{-4 \lambda  t}+2 & 1-e^{-4 \lambda  t} \\
 e^{-4 \lambda  t}-2 e^{-2 \lambda  t}+1 & 2-2 e^{-4 \lambda  t} & e^{-4 \lambda  t}+2 e^{-2 \lambda  t}+1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Is there anyway this can be solved using ODE?

Comment: @codelearner My first equation $P'(t) = AP(t)$ is a system of coupled ODEs. But there are too many of them to solve without any linear algebra trick. Maybe as you mentioned, symmetry could help, but I couldn't think of a way to use any symmetry.

Comment: Your answer has a symmetry though, where the cell (1,2) which is $2−2^{−4}$ is equal to the cell (3,2) and similarly the cell (2,1) which is $1−^{−4}$ is the same as the cell (2,3). So isn't that the symmetry we can use?